# Windows Font replacement when specified font is missing

Tags: windows, winforms, fonts

I have some software that was coded to use a certain font. I since changed my mind about the font and wanted to use Sans Serif. Before changing any code I deleted the old font from the PC I was running it on and the software still ran successfully albeit with some sizing issues. It is using Sans Serif even though the only font I have referenced in the code is no longer installed. I have searched for hours about how and why it is doing this but can't find any concrete answers. 
Could somebody explain why it does this?
Is there any way of changing the default fallback font?

Answer (score 0):

Windows will usually do font substitution when it cannot find a font as specified. The documentation for the [System.Drawing.Font class constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/164w6x6z(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

*If the familyName parameter specifies a font that is not installed on the machine running the application or is not supported, Microsoft Sans Serif will be substituted.*

I believe for Winforms controls though, the substitution may be even more involved since a control's font can be inherited from the parent container and/or window *and* there are also a number of fonts defined for the current theme by the system that may be used (see [Control.Font](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.font(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SystemFonts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemfonts(v=vs.110).aspx) docs).

There used to be an applet in control panel that allowed you to adjust the default system fonts, colors and sizes but I am unable to find it in the latest version of Windows 10.